# Function is changing global variable

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I'm trying to change a given list, *table*, replacing its values when in the same position of another list, *word*, is a string and them print it as a string.

That is working. The problem is that when I try to print *word* after executing the function, the list is changed.

```
def table_printer ( board, text):
    returned_table = ''
    copy = text
    for i in text:
        if type(i) == str:
            board[ copy.index(i) ] = i
            copy[ copy.index(i) ] = 1
    for i in board: 
        returned_table += ' ' + i + ''
    return returned_table

table = ['_','_','_','_','_']
word = [ 'p', 1, 'a', 3, 'a' ]

printed = table_printer( table, word )

print(printed)
print(word)
```

The output I'm getting

```
p 1 a 3 a
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The output I'm expecting

```
p 1 a 3 a
[ 'p', 1, 'a', 3, 'a' ]
```

Comment: `copy = text` doesn't make a copy. Both variables are references to the same list. Use `copy = text.copy()`

Comment: `board` is a reference to the same list as `table`. Modifying one modifies the other. Use `board = board.copy()` to make a copy.

Comment: Note that `copy.index(i)` will not be the current index of the loop if there are duplicate values in `copy`. Use `for index, i in enumerate(text):` to get the indexes properly.